# How to reload static methods on Android runtime

Tags: java, android, static

I'm currently working on changing locale dynamically on Android application. When user's locale changes, I store the information in SharedPreferences, and every Activity refer to the locale information when it is created.

However, I have some problem with my static methods all over my app especially in my Util classes. I use locale-specific strings in my static methods, but they are not reloaded since they are already on the memory.

It seems like android reloads all classes when device locale changes, since changing the device language/locale brings up all appropriate locale strings. How can I do this manually after changing user language?

Following is my code which is called in **onConfigurationChanged** of my application, and **attachBaseContext** of my activity.

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());

config.setLocale(getLocale());
context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
```

**Updated**
This is one example of my code that has problem related to static method.

```
public static String convertPassedDayFormat(Date date) {
    BaseApplication app = BaseApplication.get();
    int diffDay = diffDayFromCurrent(date);
    if (diffDay < 1) return app.getString(R.string.word_today);
    if (diffDay < 2) return app.getString(R.string.word_yesterday);
    if (diffDay < 4) return String.format(app.getString(R.string.word_day_passed), diffDay);
    return convertFormat(date, app.getString(R.string.format_print_day_year));
}
```

This part of the code would not return appropriate string.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve , that your app support multi language

Comment: @warlock it is not necessarily multi-language, but the app language should follow the user's dedicated language. So after signin/signup, the app should display appropriate language for the user.

Comment: BTW, the logic I use for changing locale is basically the same as supporting multi-language.

Comment: @confuoco why don't you just restart your application when locale ins changed in your application.

Comment: i Actually don't understand your problem, can you please elaborate more

Comment: @warlock My problem occurs when device locale and my user's language preference differs. When the app starts and static classes are loaded, the string resources refer to the device locale(e.g. japanese). However, after changing the user's(not device) locale to english or something, everything would change but not the strings in the static methods. This causes problems in my util classes.

Comment: @HasifSeyd same problem with my comment above. Static methods are on the memory even before application's onCreate.

Comment: You just need to call the static methods / update their values to whatever you want them to be when you need them to be changed.

Comment: I updated my question, hope it gives you more hint about the problem.

Comment: @confuoco why are you trying to get the string from BaseApplication which is also static, this is not proper. you should instead pass context as parameter to your static method

Answer (score 0):

the issue of your problem is inside your static method `convertPassedDayFormat`() for getting  the string resource, you are using old context which may not contain the updated configuration (since it is static)

What you have to do is , instead of getting Static context method from `BaseApplication.get()` ,you should pass your fresh context as parameter to your static method like shown below

```
public static String convertPassedDayFormat(Date date, Context app) {

    int diffDay = diffDayFromCurrent(date);
    if (diffDay < 1) return app.getString(R.string.word_today);
    if (diffDay < 2) return app.getString(R.string.word_yesterday);
    if (diffDay < 4) return String.format(app.getString(R.string.word_day_passed), diffDay);
    return convertFormat(date, app.getString(R.string.format_print_day_year));
}
```

Comment: I guess this is the right solution.. but is there any way I can refresh my BaseApplication?